# Fourier transform of the square of the triangle fuction

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $$f(t)=\begin{cases}0,&|t|\geqslant 1\\1-|t|,&|t|<1\end{cases}.$$ Compute the Fourier transform of $(f(t))^{2}$.

So I am a beginner with Fourier transformations and got stuck with this question. My attempt was to try and use convolution in some way as $f(t) = \widehat{g(x)}$ but I am unable to figure out how to do this. This is the final part of a course in complex analysis so the information I have available is not particularly detailed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\on{f}\pars{t} & \equiv
\bracks{-1 < t < 0}\pars{1 + t}
\\[2mm] & +\,\,
\bracks{0 < t < 1}\pars{1 - t}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{\verts{t} < 1}\pars{1 - \verts{t}}
\\[5mm] \implies
\on{f}^{2}\pars{t} & = \bracks{\verts{t} < 1}
\pars{1 - \verts{t}}^{\,2}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\varphi\pars{\omega} & \equiv
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\on{f}^{2}\pars{t}
\expo{-\ic\omega t}\,\dd t =
\int_{-1}^{1}\pars{1 - \verts{t}}^{\,2}
\expo{-\ic\omega t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{\,2}
\cos\pars{\omega t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{4\,{\omega - \sin\pars{\omega} \over \omega^{3}}} \\ &\
\end{align}